# How can I output elemets of LinkedList side by side?

Tags: java, string, methods, linked-list, output

I really need some help I am struggling since 1 week and I don't find any useful things.  That is what I am trying to achieve:

```
 * January 2017            February 2017            March 2017
 * So|01|            |1    Mi|01|            |32    Mi|01|            |60
 * Mo|02|            |2    Do|02|            |33    Do|02|            |61
 * Di|03|            |3    Fr|03|            |34    Fr|03|            |62
 * Mi|04|            |4    Sa|04|            |35    Sa|04|            |63
 * Do|05|            |5    So|05|            |36    So|05|            |64
 * Fr|06|            |6    Mo|06|            |37    Mo|06|            |65
```

Thats my declaration and initialization.

```
private final String[] monthname= {null, "Januar", "Februar", "Maerz", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli",
        "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"};
private final String[] weekdayShort= {"So", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa"};

private final int[][] monthLengths= {
        {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31},
        {0, 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31}
};
private CalenderFunction cf = new CalenderFunction();
private LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> planlist = new LinkedList<>();
private int year = 2017; // Default year
private String weekDayName;
private Calender calender = new Calender();
```

That is how I build my monthpaper.

```
public LinkedList<String> buildMonth(int month) {

        LinkedList<String> monthList = new LinkedList<>();
        String header = this.monthName[month] + " " + this.year;
        monthList.add(header);

        int lengthOfTheMonth= calender.getLengthOfTheMonth(year, month);
        for (int day = 1; day <= lengthOfTheMonth; day++) {
            for (int weekday = 0; weekday < 7; weekday++) {
                String weDay = calender.getDayOfTheWeek(weekday);
                this.weekDayName= weDay;
            }

            String dayOfTheMonth= this.calender.getTwoLetters(day);
            monthList.add(this.weekDayName+"|"+dayOfTheMonth.toString()+"|");

        }
        return monthList;
    }
```

Here is my Output Method.

```
public String getYearplan(int from, int until) {

        if (from <= until) {
            for (int i = from; i <= until; i++) {
                LinkedList<String> month = buildMonth(i);
                this.planlist.add(month);
                }

                for (LinkedList<String> months: planlist) {
                    for (String s : months) {
                        System.out.println(s);
                    }
            }
        }
```

Thats now my Output.

```
        January 2016
    Sa|01|
    Sa|02|
    Sa|03|
    Sa|04|
    Sa|05|
...
    February 2016
    Sa|01|
    Sa|02|
    Sa|03|
    Sa|04|
    Sa|05|
 ...
```

My Main Question how can I output this side by side.

Comment: ^ I would sooner pad with spaces than tabs, since terminal tab widths are somewhat unpredictable and alignments could easily break.

Comment: You can't build each month and then print everything in that month, one at a time.  You will have to build all the months first.  Then, to print things side by side, you'll need a loop that gets the first element of all the month lists, or 4 of the month lists, and prints them; then gets the second element of the same month lists and prints them; then gets the third element of the same month lists and prints them, etc.  This involves going through several lists in parallel, which you can't do with a simple `for (String s : months)`-type statement.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz I'm pretty much opposed to using tabs for anything, period, because they behave differently on different displays _and_ in different text editors.  You can get a similar effect without tabs by using something like `%-16s` in a `printf` or `String.format`.

Answer (score 0):

You need smarter code instead of

```
for (LinkedList<String> months: planlist) {
    for (String s : months) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Something like this:

```
List<String> lines = new LinkedList<>();
for(int i=0; i<=31; i++) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (LinkedList<String> months: planlist) {
        String dayValue = (i<months.size()) ? months.get(i) : " ";
        sb.append(dayValue).append("\t\t");
    }
    sb.append("\n");
    lines.add(sb.toString());
}

for(String line: lines) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

An idea is to print your year calendar line by line for all months. 
We build lines from your months array. For first line we take 0 item from month (title), next - first day from each month and so on.

Try to solve your task in this way.

Answer (score 0):

To print that output, using the Java 8 Time API, you could do this:

```
private static void printCalendar(Year year, Locale locale) {
    YearMonth[] months = new YearMonth[12];
    for (int i = 0; i < months.length; i++)
        months[i] = year.atMonth(i + 1);

    DateTimeFormatter monthFmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM uuuu")
                                                  .withLocale(locale);
    System.out.print(" * ");
    for (YearMonth month : months)
        System.out.printf("%-24s", monthFmt.format(month));
    System.out.println();
    for (int dayOfMonth = 1; dayOfMonth <= 31; dayOfMonth++) {
        System.out.print(" * ");
        for (YearMonth month : months) {
            if (dayOfMonth <= month.lengthOfMonth()) {
                LocalDate date = month.atDay(dayOfMonth);
                int dayOfYear = date.getDayOfYear();
                String dayOfWeek = date.getDayOfWeek()
                        .getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE, locale);
                System.out.printf("%-2.2s|%02d|            |%-5d",
                                  dayOfWeek, dayOfMonth, dayOfYear);
            } else {
                System.out.print("                        ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
printCalendar(Year.now(), Locale.GERMAN);
```

*Output*

```
 * Januar 2017             Februar 2017            März 2017               April 2017              Mai 2017                Juni 2017               Juli 2017               August 2017             September 2017          Oktober 2017            November 2017           Dezember 2017           
 * So|01|            |1    Mi|01|            |32   Mi|01|            |60   Sa|01|            |91   Mo|01|            |121  Do|01|            |152  Sa|01|            |182  Di|01|            |213  Fr|01|            |244  So|01|            |274  Mi|01|            |305  Fr|01|            |335  
 * Mo|02|            |2    Do|02|            |33   Do|02|            |61   So|02|            |92   Di|02|            |122  Fr|02|            |153  So|02|            |183  Mi|02|            |214  Sa|02|            |245  Mo|02|            |275  Do|02|            |306  Sa|02|            |336  
 * Di|03|            |3    Fr|03|            |34   Fr|03|            |62   Mo|03|            |93   Mi|03|            |123  Sa|03|            |154  Mo|03|            |184  Do|03|            |215  So|03|            |246  Di|03|            |276  Fr|03|            |307  So|03|            |337  
 * Mi|04|            |4    Sa|04|            |35   Sa|04|            |63   Di|04|            |94   Do|04|            |124  So|04|            |155  Di|04|            |185  Fr|04|            |216  Mo|04|            |247  Mi|04|            |277  Sa|04|            |308  Mo|04|            |338  
 * Do|05|            |5    So|05|            |36   So|05|            |64   Mi|05|            |95   Fr|05|            |125  Mo|05|            |156  Mi|05|            |186  Sa|05|            |217  Di|05|            |248  Do|05|            |278  So|05|            |309  Di|05|            |339  
 * Fr|06|            |6    Mo|06|            |37   Mo|06|            |65   Do|06|            |96   Sa|06|            |126  Di|06|            |157  Do|06|            |187  So|06|            |218  Mi|06|            |249  Fr|06|            |279  Mo|06|            |310  Mi|06|            |340  
 * Sa|07|            |7    Di|07|            |38   Di|07|            |66   Fr|07|            |97   So|07|            |127  Mi|07|            |158  Fr|07|            |188  Mo|07|            |219  Do|07|            |250  Sa|07|            |280  Di|07|            |311  Do|07|            |341  
 * So|08|            |8    Mi|08|            |39   Mi|08|            |67   Sa|08|            |98   Mo|08|            |128  Do|08|            |159  Sa|08|            |189  Di|08|            |220  Fr|08|            |251  So|08|            |281  Mi|08|            |312  Fr|08|            |342  
 * Mo|09|            |9    Do|09|            |40   Do|09|            |68   So|09|            |99   Di|09|            |129  Fr|09|            |160  So|09|            |190  Mi|09|            |221  Sa|09|            |252  Mo|09|            |282  Do|09|            |313  Sa|09|            |343  
 * Di|10|            |10   Fr|10|            |41   Fr|10|            |69   Mo|10|            |100  Mi|10|            |130  Sa|10|            |161  Mo|10|            |191  Do|10|            |222  So|10|            |253  Di|10|            |283  Fr|10|            |314  So|10|            |344  
 * Mi|11|            |11   Sa|11|            |42   Sa|11|            |70   Di|11|            |101  Do|11|            |131  So|11|            |162  Di|11|            |192  Fr|11|            |223  Mo|11|            |254  Mi|11|            |284  Sa|11|            |315  Mo|11|            |345  
 * Do|12|            |12   So|12|            |43   So|12|            |71   Mi|12|            |102  Fr|12|            |132  Mo|12|            |163  Mi|12|            |193  Sa|12|            |224  Di|12|            |255  Do|12|            |285  So|12|            |316  Di|12|            |346  
 * Fr|13|            |13   Mo|13|            |44   Mo|13|            |72   Do|13|            |103  Sa|13|            |133  Di|13|            |164  Do|13|            |194  So|13|            |225  Mi|13|            |256  Fr|13|            |286  Mo|13|            |317  Mi|13|            |347  
 * Sa|14|            |14   Di|14|            |45   Di|14|            |73   Fr|14|            |104  So|14|            |134  Mi|14|            |165  Fr|14|            |195  Mo|14|            |226  Do|14|            |257  Sa|14|            |287  Di|14|            |318  Do|14|            |348  
 * So|15|            |15   Mi|15|            |46   Mi|15|            |74   Sa|15|            |105  Mo|15|            |135  Do|15|            |166  Sa|15|            |196  Di|15|            |227  Fr|15|            |258  So|15|            |288  Mi|15|            |319  Fr|15|            |349  
 * Mo|16|            |16   Do|16|            |47   Do|16|            |75   So|16|            |106  Di|16|            |136  Fr|16|            |167  So|16|            |197  Mi|16|            |228  Sa|16|            |259  Mo|16|            |289  Do|16|            |320  Sa|16|            |350  
 * Di|17|            |17   Fr|17|            |48   Fr|17|            |76   Mo|17|            |107  Mi|17|            |137  Sa|17|            |168  Mo|17|            |198  Do|17|            |229  So|17|            |260  Di|17|            |290  Fr|17|            |321  So|17|            |351  
 * Mi|18|            |18   Sa|18|            |49   Sa|18|            |77   Di|18|            |108  Do|18|            |138  So|18|            |169  Di|18|            |199  Fr|18|            |230  Mo|18|            |261  Mi|18|            |291  Sa|18|            |322  Mo|18|            |352  
 * Do|19|            |19   So|19|            |50   So|19|            |78   Mi|19|            |109  Fr|19|            |139  Mo|19|            |170  Mi|19|            |200  Sa|19|            |231  Di|19|            |262  Do|19|            |292  So|19|            |323  Di|19|            |353  
 * Fr|20|            |20   Mo|20|            |51   Mo|20|            |79   Do|20|            |110  Sa|20|            |140  Di|20|            |171  Do|20|            |201  So|20|            |232  Mi|20|            |263  Fr|20|            |293  Mo|20|            |324  Mi|20|            |354  
 * Sa|21|            |21   Di|21|            |52   Di|21|            |80   Fr|21|            |111  So|21|            |141  Mi|21|            |172  Fr|21|            |202  Mo|21|            |233  Do|21|            |264  Sa|21|            |294  Di|21|            |325  Do|21|            |355  
 * So|22|            |22   Mi|22|            |53   Mi|22|            |81   Sa|22|            |112  Mo|22|            |142  Do|22|            |173  Sa|22|            |203  Di|22|            |234  Fr|22|            |265  So|22|            |295  Mi|22|            |326  Fr|22|            |356  
 * Mo|23|            |23   Do|23|            |54   Do|23|            |82   So|23|            |113  Di|23|            |143  Fr|23|            |174  So|23|            |204  Mi|23|            |235  Sa|23|            |266  Mo|23|            |296  Do|23|            |327  Sa|23|            |357  
 * Di|24|            |24   Fr|24|            |55   Fr|24|            |83   Mo|24|            |114  Mi|24|            |144  Sa|24|            |175  Mo|24|            |205  Do|24|            |236  So|24|            |267  Di|24|            |297  Fr|24|            |328  So|24|            |358  
 * Mi|25|            |25   Sa|25|            |56   Sa|25|            |84   Di|25|            |115  Do|25|            |145  So|25|            |176  Di|25|            |206  Fr|25|            |237  Mo|25|            |268  Mi|25|            |298  Sa|25|            |329  Mo|25|            |359  
 * Do|26|            |26   So|26|            |57   So|26|            |85   Mi|26|            |116  Fr|26|            |146  Mo|26|            |177  Mi|26|            |207  Sa|26|            |238  Di|26|            |269  Do|26|            |299  So|26|            |330  Di|26|            |360  
 * Fr|27|            |27   Mo|27|            |58   Mo|27|            |86   Do|27|            |117  Sa|27|            |147  Di|27|            |178  Do|27|            |208  So|27|            |239  Mi|27|            |270  Fr|27|            |300  Mo|27|            |331  Mi|27|            |361  
 * Sa|28|            |28   Di|28|            |59   Di|28|            |87   Fr|28|            |118  So|28|            |148  Mi|28|            |179  Fr|28|            |209  Mo|28|            |240  Do|28|            |271  Sa|28|            |301  Di|28|            |332  Do|28|            |362  
 * So|29|            |29                           Mi|29|            |88   Sa|29|            |119  Mo|29|            |149  Do|29|            |180  Sa|29|            |210  Di|29|            |241  Fr|29|            |272  So|29|            |302  Mi|29|            |333  Fr|29|            |363  
 * Mo|30|            |30                           Do|30|            |89   So|30|            |120  Di|30|            |150  Fr|30|            |181  So|30|            |211  Mi|30|            |242  Sa|30|            |273  Mo|30|            |303  Do|30|            |334  Sa|30|            |364  
 * Di|31|            |31                           Fr|31|            |90                           Mi|31|            |151                          Mo|31|            |212  Do|31|            |243                          Di|31|            |304                          So|31|            |365
```

For pre-Java 8, code would be:

```
private static void printCalendar(int year, Locale locale) {
    SimpleDateFormat monthFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy", locale);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.clear();
    int[] daysInMonth = new int[12];
    System.out.print(" * ");
    for (int month = 0; month < 12; month++) {
        cal.set(year, month, 1);
        daysInMonth[month] = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        System.out.printf("%-24s", monthFmt.format(cal.getTime()));
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int dayOfMonth = 1; dayOfMonth <= 31; dayOfMonth++) {
        System.out.print(" * ");
        for (int month = 0; month < 12; month++) {
            cal.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
            if (dayOfMonth <= daysInMonth[month]) {
                int dayOfYear = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
                String dayOfWeek = cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,
                                                      Calendar.SHORT, locale);
                System.out.printf("%-2.2s|%02d|            |%-5d",
                                  dayOfWeek, dayOfMonth, dayOfYear);
            } else {
                System.out.print("                        ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```